# laravel mix compile assets from a package in node_modules?

Tags: laravel, webpack, assets, npm-install, laravel-mix

I started using laravel-mix on my new Laravel 5.7 project to compile all the js/css into one file, which will appear in my public js/css directory (one for each page) like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .js('resources/js/create.member.js', 'public/js/backend/members')
   .sass('resources/sass/create.member.scss', 'public/css/backend/members')
   .sourceMaps();
```

Like this I want to keep the views tidy and reduce the number of assets that have to be loaded.

Everything fine so far and I understand how to work with laravel-mix. Now I installed some packages, specifically cropperjs and summernote, via npm, to my node_modules directory.

It fails when I import/require their scss/js to the scripts which are going to be compiled and placed in public by laravel-mix because it seems that these scripts (cropper.js, summernote.scss, etc...) are referencing to other assets across their origin package directory within the node_modules directory (fonts, images, etc...)

For JS I do:

```
require('../../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js');
require('../../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js');
```

Fors SCSS I do:

```
@import '~cropperjs/src/css/cropper';
@import '~summernote/src/less/summernote-bs4';
```

My question is: What is good practice when using packages, installed with npm?

Do I have to put the whole package directory to my public directory?
Do I link to the assets in the package directory which is located in the node_modules directory?
Or is their any chance left to compile them together with my other assets via laravel-mix/webpack, maybe a flag I'm missing or so?
Do I have to use any additional software like bower to make things happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For js I just use

```
import 'vue'
import 'cropperjs'
```

Usually the package documentation will tell you how to import it.

Comment: How do you import the CSS files? I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63294202/1883256).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be compiling node assets in webpack.mix... Like barghouthi said, usually the package documentation will tell you how to import the package in your js file.